# Google Compute Engine - alternative log in to VM instance if ssh port is disabled

Tags: ssh, debian, virtual-machine, firewall, google-compute-engine

I logged in to my GCE VM instance (Debian) and installed `ufw` and enabled it.

However, I forgot to enable port 22. Is there another way to log in so that I can enable port 22 without having to destroy the instance?

Answer (score 9):

No, the only way to access to the instance is through SSH.

You can enable the port 22 using a startup script like the following one:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/ufw allow 22/tcp
```

Then, you can add this startup script to your instance either using the Developers Console and pasting the code in the custom metadata section or using the cloud SDK with the command:

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata <INSTANCE NAME> --metadata-from-file startup-script=<PATH TO SCRIPT> --project <PROJECT ID>
```

This script will be executed as root every time the instance boots up or reboots so you'll need to restart your instance and you can remove the script once you have achieved your goal with:

```
gcloud compute instances remove-metadata <INSTANCE NAME> --keys startup-script --project <PROJECT ID>
```

You have more information about startup scripts in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript).

Comment: This has worked for me. I resolved it by adding metadata in Google developer console and restarting the server. Thanks.

Comment: @RodgersAndati you are my savior today.

Comment: Saved the time to delete the instance and re-create.