# cannot ssh to Google VM Engine

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

at the first day when i created the instance, i was able to SSH no problem, but after yesterday, i just couldnt connect to my instance. when i checked the console i get something like this

```
Nov  5 15:30:49 my-app kernel: [79738.555434] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens4 OUT= MAC=42:01:0a:94:00:02:42:01:0a:94:00:01:08:00 SRC=71.15.27.115 DST=10.121.0.7 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=38049 PROTO=TCP SPT=37344 DPT=22 WINDOW=60720 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

i figured its a firewall issue, but my firewall rule seems okay (assuming i did not change anything since first i created the instance). i wonder what else could be the problem? here's my fw config

```
default-allow-http
http-server 
IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
tcp:80  
Allow
1000
default

default-allow-https
https-server    
IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
tcp:443 
Allow
1000
default

default-beego-http
http-server 
IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
tcp:8080    
Allow
1000
default

default-jenkins-app
http-server 
IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
tcp:8989    
Allow
1000
default

default-allow-icmp
Apply to all    
IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
icmp    
Allow
65534
default

default-allow-internal
Apply to all    
IP ranges: 10.128.0.0/9
tcp:0-65535, udp:0-65535, 1 more    
Allow
65534
default

default-allow-rdp
Apply to all    
IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
tcp:3389    
Allow
65534
default

default-allow-ssh
Apply to all    
IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
tcp:22  
Allow
65534
default
```

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the output you’ve provided following your attempt to SSH into your instance, it looks like you’re being blocked by UFW (Uncomplicated Firewall) which is installed/enabled on the actual instance, rather than the GCP project wide firewall rules you have set (these look okay).

In order to SSH into your VM you will need to open port 22 in UFW on the instance. There are a couple of possible methods that will allow you to do this.

Firstly, see [Google Compute Engine - alternative log in to VM instance if ssh port is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28759251/google-compute-engine-alternative-log-in-to-vm-instance-if-ssh-port-is-disable/28764970#28764970) , specifically the answer by Adrián which explains how to open port 22 using a startup script. This method requires you to reboot your instance before the firewall rule is applied.

Another method which doesn’t require a reboot of the machine makes use of the Serial Console. However, in order to use this method a password  for the VM is required. This method is therefore only possible if you previously set a password on the VM (before losing access).

To connect via the Serial Console the following metadata must be added, either to the instance you are trying to connect to, or to the entire project:

```
serial-port-enable=1
```

You can apply the metadata to a specific instance like so:

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata [INSTANCE_NAME]  \
    --metadata=serial-port-enable=1
```

Or alternatively, to the entire project by running:

```
gcloud compute project-info add-metadata --metadata=serial-port-enable=1
```

After setting this metadata you can attempt to connect to the instance via the Serial Console by running the following command from the Cloud Shell:

```
gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port [INSTANCE_NAME]
```

When you have accessed the instance you will be able to manage the UFW rules. To open port 22 you can run:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/ufw allow 22/tcp
```

Once UFW port 22 is open, you should then be able to SSH into your instance from Cloud Shell or from the Console.

There is some additional info about connecting to instances via the Serial Console here:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console

Comment: When I do that, I get  the error "You are in emerg
Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked.
See sulogin(8) man page for more details.

Press Enter to continue." Pressing Enter simply writes the same message again.